# get remaining data size on tcp socket on mingw

Tags: c++, sockets, mingw

I want to get size of remaining data on tcp socket.

On linux I can do this:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
int count;
ioctl(sockfd, FIONREAD, &count);
```

But this does not work with mingw, is there any alternative solution that works in mingw?

Comment: Define what "does not work" is. Does `ioctl` return -1 or is `count` 0 after the `ioctl` call?

Comment: Compiler does not know ioctl and cant find <sys/ioctl.h>

Comment: You could Google for answer faster than posting the question on SO.

Comment: You do know that that's how much has been received and is available for you to fetch, not how much there is left of the stream, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
unsigned long count;
ioctlsocket(sockfd, FIONREAD, &count);
```